# Передать данные из трех массивов

Tags: php, массивы

Есть 3 массива $names, $types, $vals. Длина массивов одинаковая.
Выглядят примерно так

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Программа 1 
    [1] => Программа 2 
    [2] => Программа 3 
) 
Array ( 
    [0] => Очно-заочная 
    [1] => Дистанционная 
    [2] => Очно-заочная 
) 
Array ( 
    [0] => 9 
    [1] => 2 
    [2] => 5 
)
```

Как мне отправить из по email так чтобы в письме они пришли как

```
Программа 1
Очно-заочная 
9

Программа 2 
Дистанционная 
2

Программа 3
Очно-заочная
5
```

Я пытался foreach их разобрать но в таком случае их только по очереди разберу и приходят сначала данные первого массива, потом данные второго и т.д.

Comment: Вопрос: откуда прилетают такие массивы и почему на раннем этапе нельзя их сгруппировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи обычного цикла `for`

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++) {
  echo $names[$i];
  echo $types[$i];
  echo $vals[$i];
}
```

Comment: Моя тупость не знает границ))) Спасибо огромное!!!! А я пытался массивы в один многомерный пихнуть потом чего то с ними делать...